# Wordpress site - php version migration ( 5.2 - 7.x ) - Can it cause problems?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a few very old wordpress sites with lots of plugins, but most of the new plugins not working on php v 5.2. If I update the php version from 5.2 to 7.x will it cause any serious problems to the plugins, themes or current functionality of the site ? ( All the wordpress installations have not been updated since 2012, but at the moment they have been upgraded to the latest version)

Comment: It could do. Backup everything before you try it.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes, there are lots of changes and deprecated stuff in php for past few years.

Also, I think the problem is not in your php version (because I was running wordpress 4.8 on php 5.0
I think new plugins won't work because of the wordpress version. Hooks, methods, functions and lot of more "core" stuff have changed since 2012 in wordpress, so I don't think this will help you anyhow.

But anyways, if you want to try, an option would be to update your php to a 5.5 version instead of jumping straight to 7.x. (I'm currently using php 5.5 for almost all of the wordpress sites I administrate)

The latest stable version of php5 is PHP 5.5.38 which you can find here http://php.net/downloads.php#gpg-5.5.

Depending on your OS, you will have a method to update it (but that's already a new question)
For now, I suggest to test them on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress core recommends using the PHP above 7. The issue should be you making a backup of your website files and database. Deactivate the plugins. Update Wordpress core to 4.9.1 and then re activate one plugin at a time.